# Управление задержкой display:none

Tags: transition, css

Добрый день.

Есть задача: сделать задержку скрытия элемента (меню второго уровня). Как это сделать на JS - догадываюсь, но хотелось бы обойтись одним CSS.

Если вместо display использовать visibility, то все хорошо:

```
.menu.second {
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.menu.second:hover {
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  transition-delay:0s;
}
```

Но мне необходимо именно display:block и display:none.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Так вроде бы свойства display не поддерживаются transition.

Comment: @Deonis, можно ли как-то по-другому реализовать подобный эффект (задержка display:none) только с помощью CSS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property

Comment: а можно узнать какая необходимость может быть вообще для использования display: none ?

Comment: @zb' очевидно в том, чтобы объект не занимал места на странице. Других необходимостей просто не бывает. Даже метод исключения перед одним вариантом бессилен.

Comment: @VostokSisters и что мешает использовать в таком случае height/width ?

Comment: @zb, ну иногда мешает. Могут быть проблемки в анимации, я уже с таким сталкивался.

Comment: @VostokSisters забавно то, что в примере выше :hover вообще не бывает, что visibility, что display: none не принимает событий мыши :)

Comment: А может действительно менять высоту и ширину элемента? display не поддается анимации с помощью css, значит надо делать через js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так же можно и `width` и `height` поставить `0` , задержка будет работать , на `display` `transition` не отрабатывает , либо применять js.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы не сможете навести мышь на элемент который не занимает место в DOM, т.е. у которого стиль `display: none;`
2. Попробуйте через `position: absolute;`.
   т.е. как-то так.

   ```
   .menu.second {
     position: absolute;
     visibility:hidden;
     opacity:0;
     transition:visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
   }
   .menu.second:hover {
     position: static;
     visibility:visible;
     opacity:1;
     transition-delay:0s;
   }
   ```

   Но проблема с активацией объекта (наведением мыши) остаётся.

Comment: _Но мне необходимо именно display:block и display:none_ - это требование из задание.